# Why do some shared libraries end with d.so rather than .so?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

Recently I have been working with DART physics engine.

And I found that the shared libraries would have one version named like "libdart-gui.so" and another version named like "libdart-guid.so". I wonder why is there a d.so version? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those ending with `xxxxxd.so` are probably versions which were compiled with debug mode compiler flags.
That's a convention at best, and not a general rule.

Comment: Thanks!! That makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned this is typically to differentiate debug versus non-debug versions of a shared library. On some systems (such as Windows) mixing libraries built with debug and libraries built without debug can be problematic, so it is useful to be able to easily distinguish them.

Comment: _"such as Windows"_ Note that on windows the shared libraries don't have `.so` extensions, but rather `.dll`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!